# If Moran's I is non-significant can I treat my samples as being independent?

Tags: sampling, autocorrelation, spatial, independence

I have a set of data collected as part of a hydroacoustic survey-- essentially a boat drove back and forth over a harbour and took a snapshot of the fish biomass/density underneath the boat every 5 minutes using a sonar-like device. I was worried that all of these snap-shots could be considered pseudoreplicates in that they wouldn't be independent of each other-- i.e. fish sampled at time X could be resampled at time X+1 if they happened to move with the boat. To correct for this I performed a test of spatial independence using a Moran's I test, which came back as non-significant. I also compared the delta AICs of models that included a spatial correction factor and the basic model with no spatial correction, and the basic model had a lower score. Does this mean that I can consider my samples collected via the hydroacoustic survey as being independent from one another and proceed with non-spatial corrected analyses?

Comment: Since Moran's I requires the data to be collected on a grid (or at least on a graph with meaningful, well-defined spatial weights) and yours were not, it is hard to see how this statistic would be useful or give accurate information about spatial correlation.  What to do depends on how you plan to use these data: what kinds of analyses are you referring to at the end?

Comment: @whuber I used the Lat Longs to obtain a Moran's I value and correct for spatial variance following the methods on this site https://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-identify-and-remove-spatial.html ultimately I want to be able to construct a model which includes independent variables like: level of turbidity (binary variable); distance from shore, depth, and slope of bottom (all continuous), to determine which factors have a significant effect on fish density, biomass, number of schools of fish, and other continuous dependent variables.

Comment: In my experience analyzing data just like these (biological or environmental observations taken from boats zigzagging slowly across a harbor or river), it is important to assess and (potentially) account for the *serial correlation* in the observations over time.  That at least reduces the problem to a one-dimensional one and provides access to techniques of time series analysis. Because this approach handles the temporal complications well and is a good proxy for spatial correlations, I believe it will be more powerful than anything like Moran's I.

Comment: @whuber what test do I use to assess if there's significant serial correlation/remove the effect of serial correlation? Could I just add sampling time to my spatial model?

Comment: If the sampling times were obtained at regular (or nearly regular) intervals, then you can ignore location for this purpose and use standard time-series analyses to estimate the autocorrelation function (acf).